# SSRS Report preview shows image in different location than PDF Exported version

Tags: c#, pdf, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015

I have used Visual Studio 2015 to create a report. The reports has a few images

- Tick - Passed
- Cross - Failed
- X - No data has been found.

The report during design time in Visual Studio 2015 looks like this
[image: VS2015 SSRS Report Design Time]

When I preview the report in visual studio 2015 the report is displayed like so

[image: VS2015 SSRS Report Preview]

When i PDF the report I see this which is correct
[image: PDF Report]

The PDF version is correct however why does the preview not show what will be in the PDF?

Comment: Is this a real show-stopper, or does simply just annoy you?

Comment: @R.Richards - Thanks for your response. This is not a show stopper at the moment, perhaps in the future. Especially when customer views the report in Reporting services the tick might not be at the correct location however when they print as PDF it will be fine. Hope i answered your question.

Comment: So, you see this same behavior in a web browser when the report is deployed on Report Manager? If so, this may be a difference in the rendering engines. I have seen where this does happen. I am always glad that what I end up delivering to the user looks right. Viewing reports in the browser can be hit or miss.

Comment: look for any warnings about overlapping items, these are not rendered consistently across different rendering engines and might be the cause of the discrepancies you see.